# How can I see the values of the variables from a Perl trace?

Tags: perl

My target is to debug (step by step) the `sample.pl` script below.

The problem: I don’t get the real values of the variables ($top_number , $x , $total).

My question: how to see the real integer values of ($top_number , $x , $total)
from the trace output?

What needs to change in `perl -d:Trace` in order to get numbers, and not: $top_number , $x , $total ?

Example from the trace output:

```
[root@linux /tmp]# perl -d:Trace ./sample.pl 
>> ./sampl.pl:9: $top_number = 100;
>> ./sampl.pl:10: $x = 1;
>> ./sampl.pl:11: $total = 0;
>> ./sampl.pl:12: while ( $x <= $top_number ) {
>> ./sampl.pl:13:       $total = $total + $x;   # short form: $total += $x;
>> ./sampl.pl:14:       $x += 1;                # do you follow this short form?
>> ./sampl.pl:13:       $total = $total + $x;   # short form: $total += $x;
>> ./sampl.pl:14:       $x += 1;                # do you follow this short form?
>> ./sampl.pl:13:       $total = $total + $x;   # short form: $total += $x;
>> ./sampl.pl:14:       $x += 1;                # do you follow this short form?
.
.

[root@linux /tmp]#more sample.pl script

#!/usr/bin/perl 


$top_number = 100;
$x = 1;
$total = 0;
while ( $x <= $top_number ) {
    $total = $total + $x;   # short form: $total += $x;
    $x += 1;                # do you follow this short form?
}

print "The total from 1 to $top_number is $total\n";
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you want to see the values of the `$x` and `$total` variables for each iteration through the loop. There is no indication from the POD for [Devel::Trace](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel%3a%3aTrace) that it can do that.

However, [Devel::DumpTrace](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel%3a%3aDumpTrace) can.

```
perl -d:DumpTrace ./sample.pl

>>>>> hw.pl:7:      $top_number:100 = 100;
>>>>> hw.pl:8:      $x:1 = 1;
>>>>> hw.pl:9:      $total:0 = 0;
>>>>> hw.pl:10:     while ( $x:1 <= $top_number:100 ) {
>>>>> hw.pl:11:         $total:1 = $total:0 + $x:1;   # short form: $total:0 += $x:1;
>>>>> hw.pl:12:         $x:2 += 1;                # do you follow this short form?
>>>>> hw.pl:11:         $total:3 = $total:1 + $x:2;   # short form: $total:1 += $x:2;
>>>>> hw.pl:12:         $x:3 += 1;                # do you follow this short form?
>>>>> hw.pl:11:         $total:6 = $total:3 + $x:3;   # short form: $total:3 += $x:3;
```

Comment: `Devel::DumpTrace` was released just a few days ago. Be gentle and report any bugs you find. :-)

Comment: @Mob dont worry I will do that

Comment: @ hi again I get the error :  perl -d:DumpTrace ./sampl.pl
Can't locate PadWalker.pm in @INC ? why

Comment: @mob see that from the makefile:  perl Makefile.PL

This distribution comes with a PPI-based module.
Install the PPI distribution on your system
to make use of it.

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning: prerequisite PadWalker 0 not found.
Writing Makefile for Devel::DumpTrace

Comment: @Mob another thing (from my linux machine - maybe because the perl version is not as required?): perl -v This is perl, v5.8.8 built for i686-linux

Comment: `PadWalker` is required for `Devel::DumpTrace`. `PPI` is optional but recommended. There's a single line in the distribution that uses the smart match operator (`~~`) which makes it incompatible with Perl v<=5.10. I'll fix that and update it tonight.

Comment: @MOb thanx allot - please send here msg when it will finshed

Comment: v0.08 available [here](http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/M/MO/MOB/Devel-DumpTrace-0.08.tar.gz) now, and on CPAN mirrors in a day or two.

Comment: Hi Mob see the folowing I still have the problem (PadWalker 0 not found): [root@linux /tmp]# cd Devel-DumpTrace-0.08 [root@linux /tmp/Devel-DumpTrace-0.08]# perl Makefile.PL This distribution comes with a PPI-based module. Install the PPI distribution on your system to make use of it. Warning: prerequisite PadWalker 0 not found. Writing Makefile for Devel::DumpTrace [root@linux /tmp/Devel-DumpTrace-0.08]#

Comment: @Mob maybe I need to install also the PadWalker module?

Comment: Yes, `PadWalker` must be installed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`Variable::Magic`](http://search.cpan.org/~vpit/Variable-Magic-0.46/). It could be a solution for variable "tracing".

Comment: but this mean that I need to run with perl -d ? anyway ?